# Unknown error with my code

Tags: python

For some reason this is giving me a invalid syntax error at all of the defined functions(well inside them) and im really confused help. I am not sure whats wrong so any help will be helpful for me thank you very very very much all.

code:

```
from turtle import*
x=0
y=0
#by importing using 'from' lets you minimise the need to write turtle.forward

"""
forward (50) # moves the turtle forward 50 steps
right (90) # turns the turtle to the right 90 degress
pencolor("red")  # sets the pencolor.  Needs to be written before drawing the shape
fillcolor("blue")    #always needs to be written before begin fill 
fillcolor("#FF0000")  #fills with a hexadecimal color
colormode(255) #changes the color fill option to use 0-255 rather than values from 0-1.
fillcolor(0,255,0) #shows how to use R G B values (to fill with red in this case)
begin_fill()  #needs to be written before you begin drawing a shape
end_fill()  #needs to be written after you have finished drawing a shape
pensize(10) # needs to be used before giving draw commands
penup() # allows the turtle to be moved to other locations without drawing
bgcolor("orange") # fills the background of the whole drawing canvas
pendown() # normally the pen is down from the start but you may need to use pendown after lifting the penup
speed(5) #from 0 to 10, 0 being the fastest.  You need to specify the speed before writing the drawing instructions
done() # completes the drawing
"""

# start your code here

def turtleForward():
    print("How far forward do you want to go?")
    forward = input()
    forward ((int(forward))
    print("Want to go forward again?  (y) (n)")
    moreForward = input()
    if moreForward == y:
        turtleFoward()



def turtleRight():
    print("How far right do you want to go?")
    right = input()
    right ((int(right))
    print("Want to go right again?  (y) (n)")
    moreRight = input()
    if moreRight == y:
        turtleRight()


def turtleLeft():
    print("How far left do you want to go?")
    left = input()
    left ((int(left))
    print("Want to go left again?  (y) (n)")
    moreLeft = input()
    if moreLeft == y:
        turtleLeft()

def penColour():
    print("What pen colour would you like?")
    colour = input()
    pencolor (colour)


def menu():
    print("""Option 1. Set pen colour.
Option 2. Go forward.
Option 3. Go right.
Option 4. Go left.
Option 5. Quit.""")
    optionChoice = input()
    if optionChoice == '1':
        pencolour()
    elif optionChoice == '2':
        turtleForward()
    elif optionChoice == '3':
        turtleRight()
    elif optionChoice == '4':
        turtleLeft()
    elif optionChoice == '5':
        x = 1







print("Hello. Welcome to the turtle program I have made.")
while x == y:
    menu()
```

Comment: What does that mean? O.o

Comment: Can you please paste the complete traceback?

Comment: It wont give a traceback, just gives pop up saying invalid syntax and sends me to all of my second print functions in my defined functions.

Comment: This is the worst title for a question ever. It does not say anything. Please make your question more specific. In what language are you coding would be a nice starter...

Comment: Didn't know you didn't need the space between `t` and `*` in `from turtle import*`. Is _that_ a syntax error?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code, thanks for the help, but it crashes when it opens the turtle drawer

Comment: I'm glad you fixxed your code yourself, as that is the best way to learn... maybe read [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one open parenthesis too many on this line:

```
forward ((int(forward))
#       12   3       32
```

Remove one at the start:

```
forward(int(forward))
#      1   2       21
```

otherwise Python won't know until the *next* line that something is missing.

You make the same mistake another two times:

```
right ((int(right))
```

and

```
left ((int(left))
```

The next problem is that you are trying to use the same name for both a `turtle` function and a local variable:

```
forward = input()
forward(int(forward))
```

This won't work; Python now sees the string result from `input()` when referencing `forward`. Give the result from the `input()` function a *different* name:

```
steps = input()
forward(int(steps))
```

Again, this applies to the other two functions as well.

Next problem is when you are asking if the user wants to move forward some more:

```
print "Want to go forward again?  (y) (n)"
moreForward = input()
if moreForward == y:
    turtleFoward()
```

You are comparing against the global `y` variable there, not the *string* `'y'`. You probably don't want to use recursion here either; better make that a loop:

```
def turtleForward():
    while True:
        steps = input("How far forward do you want to go? ")
        forward(int(steps))
        moreForward = input("Want to go forward again?  (y) (n)")
        if moreForward.lower() != 'y':
            return
```

Comment: And he should choose a different variable name from the name of the function he's calling...this is a perfect example why `from foo import *` is risky.

Comment: Martijn you are a hero.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code, thanks for the help, but it crashes when it opens the turtle drawer

Comment: @Flux: The `turtleForward()` method as I posted it works for me. Without a specific error there is not much I can do to help you further here.

Answer (score 0):

```
forward ((int(forward))
```

this is the wrong line, you have to remove a bracket like this:

```
forward (int(forward))
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code, thanks for the help, but it crashes when it opens the turtle drawer.

Answer (score -1):

Working Code

```
    from turtle import*
    x=0
    y=0
    #by importing using 'from' lets you minimise the need to write turtle.forward

    """
    forward (50) # moves the turtle forward 50 steps
    right (90) # turns the turtle to the right 90 degress
    pencolor("red")  # sets the pencolor.  Needs to be written before drawing the shape
    fillcolor("blue")    #always needs to be written before begin fill 
    fillcolor("#FF0000")  #fills with a hexadecimal color
    colormode(255) #changes the color fill option to use 0-255 rather than values from 0-1.
    fillcolor(0,255,0) #shows how to use R G B values (to fill with red in this case)
    begin_fill()  #needs to be written before you begin drawing a shape
    end_fill()  #needs to be written after you have finished drawing a shape
    pensize(10) # needs to be used before giving draw commands
    penup() # allows the turtle to be moved to other locations without drawing
    bgcolor("orange") # fills the background of the whole drawing canvas
    pendown() # normally the pen is down from the start but you may need to use pendown after lifting the penup
    speed(5) #from 0 to 10, 0 being the fastest.  You need to specify the speed before writing the drawing instructions
    done() # completes the drawing
    """

    # start your code here

    def turtleForward():
        print("How far forward do you want to go?")
        forward = input()
        forward (int(forward))
        print "Want to go forward again?  (y) (n)"
        moreForward = input()
        if moreForward == y:
            turtleFoward()



    def turtleRight():
        print("How far right do you want to go?")
        right = input()
        right (int(right))
        print "Want to go right again?  (y) (n)"
        moreRight = input()
        if moreRight == y:
            turtleRight()


    def turtleLeft():
        print("How far left do you want to go?")
        left = input()
        left (int(left))
        print "Want to go left again?  (y) (n)"
        moreLeft = input()
        if moreLeft == y:
            turtleLeft()

    def pencolour():
        print("What pen colour would you like?")
        colour = input()
        pencolor (colour)


    def menu():
        print("""Option 1. Set pen colour.
    Option 2. Go forward.
    Option 3. Go right.
    Option 4. Go left.
    Option 5. Quit.""")
        optionChoice = str(input())
        if optionChoice == '1':
            pencolour()
        elif optionChoice == '2':
            turtleForward()
        elif optionChoice == '3':
            turtleRight()
        elif optionChoice == '4':
            turtleLeft()
        elif optionChoice == '5':
            x = 1







    print("Hello. Welcome to the turtle program I have made.")
    while x == y:
        menu()
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work still, there are more problems.

Comment: Working in Python 2.7.3

Comment: Compiling doesn't actually mean it is *working*. **Run the code properly**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is more problematic , can you elaborate

Comment: You left `forward` being rebound to the input, so the next line `forward(int(forward))` will raise an exception (`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`). Next problem is that `moreForward == y` wil compare against an integer, so `'y'` or `'n'` as input is never going to be equal to `0`. The OP is using Python 3, by the looks of it, but `print` is being used as a statement here, so that'll not work, leading to more errors. If the OP is using Python 2, then `input()` will evaluate `y` or `n` input, resulting in a nameerror for `n`. Etc.